# How the url is called for zend restful controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have to create a webservices using zf2 restful controller.

Restfull controller

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class JsonController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function getList()
    {
        return new JsonModel(array('data' => "Welcome to the Zend Framework Album API example"));
    }
}
```

How the url is hit to call the getList method.

Comment: You can easily find and trace the AbstractRestfulController's `onDispatch()` method to understand how request handled internally and resolving the `getList()` method on HTTP GET.

Comment: I find the way to handle it :).